# Using python sdist to create a package that includes generated files in the build directory

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, setup.py, sdist

I have generated python source files (from protocol buffer definitions) in build/generated-sources that are referenced by my setup.py script:

```
package_dir={'': 'build/generated-sources/main'},
```

But sdist.py prunes all files from the build folder.

I could copy these out of the build directory, but that seems hacky?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the --no-prune flag!